# Magic Mouse 2 driver touch scroll

Tags: drivers, mouse, apple, hid

I just recently picked up a Magic Mouse 2 after trying out my friends Magic Mouse 1. The MM has touch capabilities, and I wanted to make sure that those features worked on my Arch laptop, and they did! Well, for MM1 they did, but for the MM2, the touch scrolling does not work. Apparently there is no driver support for the MM2 yet, only for the MM1.

I figured out how to modify the existing driver (thanks to [repo](https://github.com/biggreenogre/mm2)) so that it would load for my MM2, but the touch functionality still does not work.

I read that you need to enable the touch feature of the MM2 when you connect to it, and it is off by default, so there are no touch events coming in. You only get events when you click left or right or move the mouse.

Thus, I'm looking for some guidance on how to make this mouse work. I found some [bluetooth packet logs](https://gist.github.com/rxaviers/3cfa809d03c799390ac3edbb697c7b30) from Mac that can be used where I think 'pair.txt' is the most valuable. [This file](https://pastebin.com/Q2fspzUS) has the important hid packets filtered out, but I'm not sure what to look for.

There is very little documentation on this subject so, if someone could show me da wae, it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

I've managed to make it working.
(I am using ubuntu 18.04, and the default Linux kernal was 4.15.)

Steps:
 - Upgrade Linux Kernal to 4.20 (you could use Ukuu, https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/ukuu-easy-way-to-install-mainline-kernel-ubuntu)
 - Install the driver patch: https://github.com/rohitpid/Linux-Magic-Trackpad-2-Driver
 - Reboot. Hopefully the scrolling works at this stage. 
 - You can then follow the instructions in http://sneclacson.blogspot.com/2016/09/using-apple-magic-mouse-with-ubuntu-1604.html to fine tune the scroll speed and disable middle button etc.

Comment: This worked for me after I started on the steps in the last link.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like some clever people picked up this project recently...
https://github.com/robotrovsky/Linux-Magic-Trackpad-2-Driver
https://github.com/rohitpid/Linux-Magic-Trackpad-2-Driver

Comment: I assume this is only vertically but no horizontal scrolling. Isn't it?

Comment: Note to future me: if the built-in hid_magicmouse doesn't work and can't be overridden (e.g., RHEL 8 with kernel 4.18), use a custom build of the driver as described [here](https://github.com/mwyborski/Linux-Magic-Trackpad-2-Driver/issues/6).

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays, Apple Magic Mouse 2 is supported in kernel [since Linux 5.13](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-5.13-HID-Additions). As I gather from the newer [high-resolution patch-set description](https://lkml.org/lkml/2021/7/7/581), the non-high-resolution scroll seems to have been supported since then as well.

And while on it, the high-resolution scroll will be supported [since 5.15](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Magic-Mouse-High-Res-Linux-5.15). I'm not sure if userspace is able to make use of high-resolution scroll yet, but at least the driver support will be there.